# htaccess on parent directory not permitting subdirectory WordPress view

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing a WordPress site in a subfolder for a client at peterpanos.com. His existing site (static html) is utilizing the following htaccess script to switch to some kind of mobile translation:

```
##BEGIN MOBILE (do not edit below this line)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ((.*iPhone.*)|(.*iPod.*)|(.*BlackBerry.*)|(.*Android.*Mobile.*)|(.*Windows\ CE.*)|(.*IEMobile.*)|(.*Opera\ Mini.*)|(.*Opera\ Mobi.*))
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !dm_show_classic
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no_redirect=true [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9a-z-]+\.[a-z]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_dm/s/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf|bmp|tif|mp3|wav|wma|asf|mp4|flv|mpg|avi|csv|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|tar|gz|dmg|iso)$ [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.peterpanos.com/ [R,L]
##END MOBILE
```

How can I adapt that so I can view the development site at peterpanos.com/wordpress2015? I tried pasting it into my WordPress htaccess after the usual WordPress htaccess language, replacing redirect=true with false, but no go.

Comment: peterpanos.com/wordpress2015 is reachable

Comment: FYI You should declare your `RewriteBase /` after the `RewriteEngine`

Comment: zien: not on my iphone, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

To disable mobile redirect for subdirectory just add one more condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress2015
```

Comment: i tried it in both the static html/current site's htaccess as well as my wordpress htaccess, and it didnt work. where should i put it? this is my wordpress htaccess script with your suggestion.

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /wordpress2015/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /wordpress2015/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress2015

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress `

Comment: Add this right after `RewriteEngine on` in the .htaccess from your start post and don't touch WP's .htaccess.

Comment: thank you umka, but it is still redirecting on phones to his primary mobile.peterpanos.com.